# How to create a collapsible UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I need to create a expandable and collapsible UIView of some sort and am not able to pay for a third party control.

This is basically how I would like it to behave:

At the top there should be a UIButton (or similar) that allows the user to toggle between expanded and collapsed.

When expanded I want to be able to place other UIView (e.g. calendar)and when collapsed the surrounding controls should move up.

Does anyone have any ideas how to implement this simply - noob here :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subclass a ViewController and have two methods that your button can fire like 'collapse' and 'expand', this might get you started: You can assign new selectors to UIButtons dynamically:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(eventMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Code:

```
#define COLAPSED_HEIGHT 30

-(void)expand
    {   
        CGRect s= [self getScrerenBoundsForCurrentOriantation];
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;
        f.origin.y =s.size.height-self.view.frame.size.height;  
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"expand" context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished:finished:context:)];    
        self.view.frame=f;

           //CHANGE YOUR EXPAND/COLLAPSE BUTTON HERE

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.thumbScrollerIsExpanded=YES;
    }

    -(void)collapseView
    {
        //re-factored so that this method can be called in ViewdidLoad
        CGRect s= [self getScrerenBoundsForCurrentOriantation];
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;

        f.origin.y =(s.size.height-COLAPSED_HEIGHT);

        self.view.frame = f;

        self.thumbScrollerIsExpanded=NO;    //thumbScrollerIsExpanded is a BOOL property
    }


    - (void)collapse
    {       
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"collapse" context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished:finished:context:)];    
        [self collapseView];
           //CHANGE YOUR EXPAND/COLLAPSE BUTTON HERE    
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }


-(CGRect)getScrerenBoundsForCurrentOriantation
{
    return [self getScrerenBoundsForOriantation:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];
}


-(CGRect)getScrerenBoundsForOriantation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)_orientation
{
    UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGRect fullScreenRect = screen.bounds; // always implicitly in Portrait orientation.        

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(_orientation)) 
    {
        CGRect temp;
        temp.size.width = fullScreenRect.size.height;
        temp.size.height = fullScreenRect.size.width;
        fullScreenRect = temp;      
    }

    return fullScreenRect;
}

- (void)animationFinished:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context
{   

    if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"expand"])
    {   
    //example
    }
else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"collapse"])
    {   
    //example
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a UIView (either in xib or programmatically) off screen, then use a UIView animation to slide it into your main viewing area.

The button would have an IBAction which would toggle the animation (slide in/slide out). You can slide it off screen then set UIView's hidden property to true. When you recall the IBAction, have it check if the view's hidden property is true. If it is, you know to play the animation of it sliding in, if not, then you play the animation of sliding out.